# Calculate the modulus of a number at a certan power (the number at that power is quite big)

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I want to calculate the RSA algorithm by myself . I need to calculate the modulus of a number at a certain power. The thing is that that number at that certain power can get quite big.

Here is what i want :

```
x = pow(n, p) % q
```

How can I efficiently determine x?

Comment: Obligatory remark: this is fine for study etc but never write your own encryption for something real.

Comment: i thing it kind of extends beyond limit of ulong . I'm not sure though .. you could be right .

Comment: @Henk .. i'm doing it just for fun .. i'm not going to use it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, I suggest you look at [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), which even provides the [`ModPow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow.aspx) method to do it all in a single operation :)

```
BigInteger n = ...;
BigInteger p = ...;
BigInteger q = ...;
BigInteger x = BigInteger.ModPow(n, p, q);
```

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Neither did I before this question :)

Comment: Is the source code of `BigInteger.ModPow()` available? I wonder if it is (or there is a version) tuned for when q is prime.

Comment: @Ypercube: The source of the framework is available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx .

Answer (score 8):

This is known as the [powermod function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation):

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    c := 1
    for e_prime = 1 to exponent 
        c := (c * base) mod modulus
    return c
```

This can be made more efficient by applying exponentiation by squaring:

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    result := 1
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent & 1) equals 1:
           result = (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base = (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

Comment: +1. I would only add a `base = base mod modulus` at the start of the function, to catch the case when `base` is much larger than `modulus`.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially...

```
x = 1
for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
   x = (x*n) % q
```

Theres more efficient ways such as binary exponentiation rather than this naive iteration, but this does get past the overflow problem as x is bounded by n*q

Comment: The question specifically says the number will be "quite big" and given that it's to do with crypto, I think it's reasonable to assume it won't fit in an int. What happens when `x * n` overflows to a negative number, leading to a negative intermediate result?

Comment: ok so call x, and whatever else you deem necessary, a BigInteger.  point being that no matter how big the bound is, give a large enough exponent and its going to overflow if think you can just find a huge natural number and mod once at the end, rather than taking mods along the way

Comment: I agree with your previous comment and with that your solution gets past the overflow problem. But only that. "*There's more efficient ways*" could be stated as "(my program may find the result after the end of the universe (if p is big enough) while other programs would find it in minutes".

Comment: thus i started with the 'trivally' disclaimer, and referred to those other methods.  i wasnt sure where OP is at, and you shouldnt tackle the more involved methods until knowing the naive one

Answer (score 1):

See `BigInteger.ModPow` (Fx 4+), here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to write your own version of `Modpow()`:

---

You only need the power modulo q, so your calculations don't need to use any number bigger than `q^2`, using the fact that:

```
if a = b (mod q) then a*p = b*p (mod q)
```

Therefore, when calculating the power `n^p`, after every multiplication, do a (modulo q) operation on your working variable.

---

Additionally, if q is prime, you can use Fermat's little theorem, which states that:

```
a^(q-1) = 1 (mod q)
    (when a is not a multiple of q)
```

This can be used to shorten the calculations when `p` is (much) bigger than `q`

Answer (score 0):

Although all the answers provided here are correct I mis the obvious square-and-multiply algorithm, which is the "classic" way to implement modular exponentiation.