# RSA encryption algorithm in Java: no BigIntegers

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I need to implement RSA algorithm in Java. I've found the best solution using BigIntegers, problem is that I need to work only with ints or longs. 
The encrypting is done like this: `M[i]^e mod n` where M[i] is an input char and e is a key value. I tried using the ASCII codes of chars, and with codes such as 115 and 116 I quickly get out of range. How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need to work only with ints or longs" why this restriction?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433992/calculate-the-modulus-of-a-number-at-a-certan-power-the-number-at-that-power-is

Comment: If `n<2^32` using `long`s is easy(i^2 won't overflow since i<n and n^n<2^64). Else you probably need to use int/long arrays. You just need to implement one operation: ModPow. For example using the square-and-multiply algorithm.

Comment: @Howard, this is my teachers restriction, I think, he just wants to spend my time doing dumb things. Anyway..

Comment: @Egor then please add the homework tag.

Comment: @Egor: First, add the `homework` tag. Second, implementing `modpow()`is not a dumb thing. You can try to impress your teacher by implementing and running tests (with various big values for `n`), using your solution **and** a solution with `BiGInteger`s and comparing running times.

Comment: @ypercube, Maybe, you're right, but I really don't like reimplementing things that are already done, they work and work well, and whole world uses them. I think I just need to understand those things, which I do.

Comment: @Egor: Yes reimplementing the wheel is painful, and basically pointless (in and of itself)... but I'm one of the "old school" who believes that ALL professional programmers need a grounding in "the low-level stuff". Quite often it is low-level considerations which determine the high level posibilities, regardless of whether or not you're using a "high level" language. For an illuminating (and ammusing) essay on this topic see [Back To Basics (Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html). Cheers. Keith.

Comment: @Howard BigInteger isn't designed for constant time arithmetic, whereas crypto should be resistant to timing attacks. This means you need to either blind your private key operations, or implement constant time big-integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a look at [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). This way you overcome most of the overflows in your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a bit...

```
(a * b) mod m == ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m
```

If you recall from basic math,

```
a ^ 10 = (a ^ 5) * (a ^ 5)
```

So, you can split your crazy high powers into lower powers and then take the modulo of their value (thereby keeping the value small), and then recombine them afterwards:

```
Too Big!         = Just Right!
(2 ^ 20) mod 113 = (((2 ^ 10) mod 113) * ((2 ^ 10) mod 113)) mod 113
```

I don't know if this counts as "giving it away" but my students had trouble with this once and I had no problem showing them this trick.  Besides, I presume this is more of an exercise in recursion than anything else.