# Remainder When Dividing Large Number

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when 30^74 is divided by 57?

I know normally to solve such a problem, you would use Fermat's Little Theorem, but in this case, 57 is not a prime number, so I am unsure how to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: Divide both the dividend and the divisor by 3 and you'll get a prime divisor.

Comment: 45 (I really hoped it would be 42). http://ideone.com/mpZKuj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the modulus of a number at a certan power (the number at that power is quite big)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433992/calculate-the-modulus-of-a-number-at-a-certan-power-the-number-at-that-power-is)

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics and not programming. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30^74 mod 57 = (3^74 * 10^74) mod 3*19 = 3 * [(3^73 * 10^74) mod 19]

and

(3^73 * 10^74) mod 19 = (3^(18*4) * 3 * 10^(18*4) * 10^2) mod 19

now, by a Fermst's Little Theorem ( m^(p-1) mod p = 1):

(3^73 * 10^74) mod 19 = (3 * 10^2) mod 19 = 300 mod 19 = 15

therefore

30^74 mod 57 = 3 * 15 = 45

---

The basic implementation of modular exponentiation method to get the remainder is:

```
long modular_pow( long base, long exponent, long modulus) {
    long c = 1;
    for ( long e_prim = 0; e_prim < exponent; ++e_prim) {
        c = (c * base) % modulus;
    }
    return c;
}
```

however implementation shown by @Vikram Bhat is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use modular exponentiation :-

```
modexp(a,pow) = (a*modexp(a,pow-1))%p
```

Faster modular exponentiation :-

```
public static long modexp(long a,long pow,long p) {

       if(pow==0) {
           return(1);
       }   

       long t = modexp(a,pow/2,p);
       t = (t*t)%p;

       if(pow%2==1) {
           t = (t*a)%p;
       }

       return(t);

    }
```

**Call : -**  `modexp(30,74,57)`

**Time Complexity:** `O(log(pow))`

Comment: have you written it by yourself or maybe can you provide a link to math derivation?

Comment: @piotruś i have written by myself as used it in RSA . Here is link for proof http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation